# IWbemClassObject->Put method returning WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: c++, wmi, wbem

I've got a block of C++ code in which I'm trying to call a company-specified WMI method. While attempting to build the IWbemClassObject representing the parameters, I get a WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND error message. According to the  [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa391455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this should not be a valid HRESULT.

```
/* pSvc has been setup already, all calls returned S_OK. Ugly Debugging statements have been sprinkled throughout the code. */
HRESULT hres;
IWbemClassObject* DataInClass;
IWbemClassObject* DataOutClass;
IWbemClassObject* CallingObject;
/* Grab the types of parameters we will be using for Input and Output.
DataIn and DataOut are set to the classes we will  be using */
hres = pSvc->GetObject(
    _bstr_t("ObjectName"),
    WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_WBEM_COMPLETE,
    NULL,
    &CallingObject,
    NULL
    );
cout << "GetObject:" << hres << endl;

string function_type = "MethodName";

hres = CallingObject->GetMethod(
    _bstr_t(function_type.c_str()),
    0,
    &DataInClass,
    &DataOutClass
    );
cout << "GetMethod:" << hres << endl;
if(hres == WBEM_S_NO_ERROR) cout << "No Error" << endl;
if(hres == WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND) cout << "Not found" << endl;
if(hres == WBEM_E_OUT_OF_MEMORY) cout << "OOM" << endl;
/* Create an instance of DataIn and DataOut and populate the parameters */
IWbemClassObject* DataIn;
IWbemClassObject* DataOut;
hres = DataInClass->SpawnInstance(0, &DataIn);
hres = DataOutClass->SpawnInstance(0, &DataOut);

/* NOTE: up to this point, all HRESULTS have been returning S_OK. I'm getting appropriate pointer values, so it appears that the code can connect to WMI. */

/* Set all of the parameters needed for DataIn */
VARIANT var;
// Active: true
_variant_t varActive(true);
var = varActive.Detach();
hres = DataIn->Put(_bstr_t("Active"), 0, &var, 0);
VariantClear(&var);
switch(hres){
case WBEM_E_FAILED: cout << "Failed" << endl; break;
case WBEM_E_INVALID_PARAMETER: cout << "ip" << endl; break;
case WBEM_E_INVALID_PROPERTY_TYPE: cout << "ipt" << endl; break;
case WBEM_E_OUT_OF_MEMORY: cout << "oom" << endl; break;
case WBEM_E_TYPE_MISMATCH: cout << "typem" << endl; break;
case WBEM_S_NO_ERROR: cout << "ok" << endl; break;
case WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND: cout << "WHAT!?" << endl; break; // This is the error code being returned from DataIn->Put
default: cout << "nota?" << endl; break;
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening, and how I can fix it?

Many thanks in advance,
Zach

Answer (score 1):

Typically this error comes up with "GET" commands.
In most cases the particular cause of the error depends on the WMI class you're attempting to access. For example, [WMIDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684) has this to say regarding when this error is returned when attempting to connect to a performance counter:

> When a WMI performance class is missing (i.e. 'Win32_PerfRawData_TermService_TerminalServices'), it is generally due to
>   a lack of buffer refresh of the WMI class provider exposing the WMI performance counters.
>   
> You can refresh the WMI class provider buffer with the following command:
>   
> 'WINMGMT.EXE /SYNCPERF'

In other cases, this error appears to be most commonly caused by a corrupted repository. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2465990) MS KB article for an example.

Since you mentioned a "Company specified" WMI method, I'm assuming that you've registered your own WMI provider. I would suspect that this provider is not properly registered with WMI before I go rebuilding the repository.

It's been almost a year since you asked the question, I guess you probably figured it out. If so, I think the community would appreciate you posting your results here so that other users can benefit from it.